# How to create an image mask in Xamarin Form?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Let me be more specific: I found online many examples of images clipped to frames or other shapes but I need to create a sort of template made by an png image with an hole in it and put a user image in that hole, possibly centered. How can I achieve that in xamarin forms?
Initially I thought about wrapping the mask image in a frame but it would be pretty difficult to add a secondary image inside the hole itself so I've tried positioning with AbsoluteLayout but it doesn't fit my needs, here's the xaml code, pretty simple:

```
  <ContentView.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Image Source="ftoast.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
            <Image Source="temp1.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Here's what I'm actually trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see the image (pancakes) isn't perfectly at the top of the mask but it has a bit of border.
Keep in mind that I have to save the inner image offset somewhere to create templates dynamically.

Comment: Could you please add sample snippet that you have tried

Comment: So template image("temp1png") is this calendar image layout and what you want to achieve is to place different photos(e.g. "ftoast.jpg") in some specific area of that template layout?

Comment: Exactly! I can't find anything related to this online. Well, if you have any other ideas to achieve the same thing it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="Pancake.png"/>
        <Image Source="ProfileImage.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,35,35" /> 
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the size of your image but you should have the template image before the custom image.

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image Source="CalendarTemplate.jpg" HeightRequest="468" 
           WidthRequest="216"/>
    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="Center" 
                HeightRequest="250" WidthRequest="176" Margin="20">
        <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="Pancakes.jpg" />
    </FlexLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Change the Template Height- and WidthRequest to your image size and adjust the margin and WidthRequest of the FlexLayout to your prefered border size. (The WidthRequest should be the WidthRequest of the template minus the Margin * 2). The FlexLayout will center the image if it is to small (probably the case most of the times).

Comment: The image size is in pixels, how do I convert that to dp?

Comment: As long as you keep the ratio of the image you can play around with different values what suits you. My image is 1080 × 2340px, and I divided by 5.